# qt project file Library includes

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I know that the library required can be loaded with

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/lib
```

recently I have found something like this

```
LIBS        += -L. -L/usr/lib -lphonon -lcurl -ltag -fopenmp -lsayonara_gstreamer
```

What does "**-L.**" means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uppercase **-L** increments the libraries *search path*, while lowercase **-l** add a *library*. Then **-L.** add the build directory as possible recipe of some of the listed libraries.

Comment: As additional information: "." refers to the current directory, which is usually the folder which contains the .pro file (or the shadow build folder if you are using that)